# Ruby on Rails: gem devise session logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables, company and employee, so I would like when I register an employee, his registration was also for the company that was already logged, that is, without having to have to choose which company of that employee. How would I do this in ruby on rails? I'm using gem devise to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your User Controller:

```
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.company_id = current_company.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sorry, I used the translator and it went wrong, I'm Brazilian. But I'll try to explain.

I'm using the gem devise in the company model, when you log in it can register an employee. When registering the employee, I want this employee to be automatically this company that is logged, that is, without having to manually choose which company will be his.

Comment: Okay, this should be a pretty easy fix then.  Just to clarify - you are using Devise on the company model.  This means when you log in, you log in as a company, correct?  You should have a current_company variable that Devise always sets.  It is usually current_user but if you're using company the name should change.  If this is the case in your controller you should be able to do something like this ```@new_employee.company_id = current_company.id``` Could you copy and paste the code from your Company model, User model, and whatever controller you are using for user registration?

Comment: I researched a little and what I want to do has to do with session store. I have to store the session and at the time of the employee registry, send the company data that are stored in the session, but I still do not know how I do it in rails.

Comment: First of all, could you post your Users Controller instead?  As far as sessions go, Devise does all of that for you - literally if you log in as a Company (that is how your app works, right?) then you should be able to access a variable that Devise will always have for you called ```current_company``` this variable will have an ID attribute.  That is what you want to save to your users company_id field in the User#Create action.  If you want to view current_company, try throwing this in your User#Create action at the top.  It will print to your logs.  ```puts current_company.inspect```

Comment: Right, I pasted the user controller code. Could you please give me a step by step how can I do this?

Comment: Right in between these two lines of code: ```@user = User.new(user_params) respond_to do |format|``` add the line ```@user.company_id = current_company.id``` - that's all.  It should be the third line in your Users#Create action.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your app.

Comment: Like this: 
    `@user = User.new(user_params)`
    `@user.company_id = current_company.id`
    `respond_to do |format|`
    `the rest of your code`

Comment: I want after the company to log in, it can register a user and save direct to the company that logged in, without having to choose a company for him by select.

Comment: That is exactly what this will do!  It is saving the company's ID to the User's company_id field, which is assigning that company to that user right before it saves in the create action.

Comment: After that, what should be done next? now whenever I log in to a different company and register a user, will it be saved in that different company?

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to do anything else. Yes it will be saved to the different company!  When you log in as a company, Devise saves the current_company variable.  It's like a session variable that you don't have to worry about.  When you assign the current company's id to the user's company_id field, you are assigning whichever company you are logged in as to that newly registered user.  Try it out :)

Comment: Hey, I'm happy for you!  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

**MODEL COMPANY:**

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
    has_many :user
end
```

**MODEL USER (the user is the employee):**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :company

  enum kind: { pattern: 0, admin: 1 }

  has_many :approved

  has_many :expenses

end
```

**COMPANY CONTROLLER:**

```
    class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def pesquisa
    if params[:q] != nil
    @companies = Company.where("companies.name LIKE '%"+params[:q]+"%'")
    else
      @companies = Company.all
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  # GET /companies
  # GET /companies.json
  def index
    @companies = Company.all
  end

  # GET /companies/1
  # GET /companies/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /companies/new
  def new
    @company = Company.new
  end

  # GET /companies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /companies
  # POST /companies.json
  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /companies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /companies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.update(company_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /companies/1
  # DELETE /companies/1.json
  def destroy
    @company.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to companies_url, notice: 'Company was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :responsible, :telefone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

**USER CONTROLLER**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  def pesquisa
    if params[:q] != nil
    @users = User.where("users.name LIKE '%"+params[:q]+"%'")
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :cpf, :kind, :timeid, :company_id)
    end
end
```